# show progress indicator only if there are no errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I have a login screen with firebase authentication and error validation. When a user inserts their credentials, firebase does validation and returns error code. I am translating the error then displaying it on a snack bar. My issue is on clicking of the login button, I want the progress indicator to come up and if there are any errors caught, it must stop and only the snack bar must show. My code is as follows

```
myButtonOnPressed: () async {
    try {
        final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email,
            password: password,
        );

        if (newUser != null) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
        }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        ///look for error conde in switch statement and return
        ///english error code

        String fireBaseAuthErrorCode = funcFireBaseAuthErrors(e.code);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            ///add SnackBar function
            funcSnackBar(
                errorMessage: fireBaseAuthErrorCode,
                snackBarColor: Color(snackBarColor),
                snackBarTextColor: Color(snackBarTextColor),
                snackBarTextFont: snackBarTextFont,
                snackBarTextSize: snackBarTextSize,
                showErrorDuration: kLoginScreenSnackBarDisplayDuration,
            ),
        );
    }
},
```

How on earth do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using a `StatefulWidget` - using which this can be achieved with a boolean variable and conditional rendering in the button.

```dart
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YourWidget> createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  bool authInProgress = false;

  Future<void> login() async {
    try {
      // Initiate login by setting authInProgress to true.
      setState(() {
        authInProgress = true;
      });

      final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      if (newUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ///look for error conde in switch statement and return
      ///english error code

      String fireBaseAuthErrorCode = funcFireBaseAuthErrors(e.code);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        ///add SnackBar function
        funcSnackBar(
          errorMessage: fireBaseAuthErrorCode,
          snackBarColor: Color(snackBarColor),
          snackBarTextColor: Color(snackBarTextColor),
          snackBarTextFont: snackBarTextFont,
          snackBarTextSize: snackBarTextSize,
          showErrorDuration: kLoginScreenSnackBarDisplayDuration,
        ),
      );
    } finally {
      // Regardless of the outcome, after the process is done,
      // set authInProgress to false.
      setState(() {
        authInProgress = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: login,
      child: authInProgress
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : const Text("Login"),
    );
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. Create a variable `authInProgress` with initial value of `false`, indicating that process has not yet begun.
2. In the login function, using the `setState` method set the `authInProgress` to `true` in the `try` block, and add a `finally` block, set it back to `false`. **The `finally` block will execute regardless of the outcome in the `try` block.** So, in this case - whether login fails or succeeds, finally block is always executed.
3. I have used the `ElevatedButton` for this case, in which, if `authInProgress` is `true`, we will render `CircularProgressIndicator()`, else the `Text()`, that you want to display.

P.S.

- I have written the `login()` outside of `build()` for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful. If I wanted the get the Circular indicator to be a the center of the screen as not on the pressed button, where would I place my authInProgress
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : const Text("Login"),